# Spring Data JPA, how to create different findById and findByIdWithLock

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have UserService and UserRepository, in UserService I want to be able to call:
 - repository.findById which would use default spring implementation
 - repository.findByIdWithLock which would correspond to findById with @Lock annotation.

I would like to avoid using @Query, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far.

Comment: Deinum, I am not sure what to try as in repository you can't write @Lock findByIdWithLock, spring won't be able to parse it...